# Which version of gcc is installed on Mac (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, llvm, osx-yosemite

I am confused by what version of gcc is installed on my Mac, which is has OS X Yosemite (10.10.5) installed on it. I also have Xcode v6.3.1 installed.

Entering the commands below reveals the following info:

```
gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix

clang -v
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix

which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

which clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

As far as I can tell, gcc is not aliased to clang.

Can someone please enlighten me what this means?

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of XCode gcc and clang are linked to the same binary in the SDK. clang will say that it's at least gcc 4.2, this is a little weird, but works for lots of software that checks for gcc and it is compatible in general.

```
echristo@dzur ~> /usr/bin/clang -v
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
echristo@dzur ~> /usr/bin/gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

If you take a look at the directory InstalledDir you can see the programs that are actually there.

Comment: Where does the info about `InstalledDir` come from? I don't see that when I run `clang -v`.

Comment: Looks like my clang is at least a release newer than yours, might be new there is my guess. Try updating your xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to know what version of gcc should I install on my Yosemite, since most of UNIX tools need GCC it is a vital package.

if gcc -version doesn't shows the version, it means you do not have one.

you need to install a gcc first, then check for its version! funny? but according to your Xcode command line and OS version you have not a lot of options, let the brew decide which version you should install, It also installs dependencies.

To install GCC,

1. install Homebrew [From HomeBrew Website](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVkY3ropDTAhUCKcAKHZS3B2oQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrew.sh%2F&usg=AFQjCNEK9RsqMgSc6Ai3v0jEiRniLzuTIQ&bvm=bv.152174688,bs.2,d.d2s)
2. Open Terminal
3. Run command: brew install gcc

I have installed my GCC just now, here is the snapshot, notice the dependent module names and the gcc version at the following picture, they are Yosemite tailored :

[image]